# How to check/uncheck CheckedTextView (child items) items inside ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, checkedtextview

**My design :**  I have created a custom adapter(`SignalsExpandableListAdapter)`with a CheckedTextView for my ExpandableListView.

```
public class SignalsExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> listDataHandler;
private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;

public SignalsExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHandler, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHandler = listDataHandler;
    this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
}
```

Then data is filled inside a fragment with HashMap and List as below. This works well. I can see children and parent elements inside my ExpandableListView.

```
ArrayList<List<String[]>> deviceMList = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String[]> mList = new ArrayList<>();
deviceMList.add(mList);
```

**What I'm looking for I :** When I select any child (can be multiple) I want to indicate that selection with a tick using CheckedTextView. And also I want to uncheck when I select any checked child item. (A simple check/uncheck design ). As well when any child is selected another function is called for plotting. This is where I got stuck. Every time when I select one child, random multiple children checkedTextViews are also indicated as checked not only the one I select.

After some searching I tried 3 attempts to overcome this and to check only the child I select. But it seems like neither of my attempts is working. I'm not sure what is going on. My attempts are mentioned below. I would really appreciate any suggestions on this.

I tried Attempt 4 (Described below in section II.) but still seems like check/unchecks is not happening in real-time.

**Attempt 1 :** Trying to make checked true inside Fragment

```
listAdapter = new SignalsExpandableListAdapter(context,signalsListDataHeader,signalsListHash);
signalsExpandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
signalsExpandableListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
//tickCheckboxes();

signalsExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        CheckedTextView sensorCheckedView  = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sensorsCheckedTextView);
        if(!mService.mPlotManager.ifPropertyExist(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition))) {
            sensorCheckedView.setChecked(true);
            try {
                if(Plot==null) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Plot is null!");
                }
                mService.mPlotManager.addSignal(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition), Plot);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error! + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            mService.mPlotManager.removeSignal(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
            //signalsExpandableListView.setItemChecked(childPosition,false);
            sensorCheckedView.setChecked(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Attempt 2 :** Creating a different function and call it inside Fragment. Created function is as below and function calling is commented above Attempt 1.

```
//loop through groups and then children
public void tickCheckboxes() {
    //CheckedTextView sensorCheckedView  = (CheckedTextView) signalsExpandableListView.findViewById(R.id.sensorsCheckedTextView);
    for (int i = 0; i < deviceMList.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < deviceMList.get(i).size(); j++) {
            if (mService.mPlotManager.ifPropertyExist(deviceMList.get(i).get(j))) {
                signalsExpandableListView.setItemChecked(j, true);
                //sensorCheckedView.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                signalsExpandableListView.setItemChecked(j, false);
                //sensorCheckedView.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempt 3 :** Accessing child element with ExpandableListView Adapter. I updated the `getChildView()` method as below.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensors_list_items,null);
    }
    CheckedTextView txtListChild = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById((R.id.sensorsCheckedTextView));
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (txtListChild.isChecked()) {
                txtListChild.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                txtListChild.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

**List Items xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/sensorsCheckedTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Group xml :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deviceNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Device Name"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**What I'm looking for II :** For check/uncheck I modified Adapter as in Attempt 4 with the help of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61996186/11375743) mentioned below.  I cannot see the `checked` mark in real-time. When I click a child then I want to scroll up/down to visually see the checkmark. Same as with the uncheck. It is strange. It seems like a kind of "refreshing" is required to see the check/uncheck state in real-time. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get rid of this.

Thank you.

**Attempt 4:** Modified adapter. This works for a check/uncheck but can not visually see it in real-time.

```
public class SignalsExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHandler;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;
    private MService mService;
    private ArrayList<List<String[]>> deviceMList ;

    public SignalsExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHandler, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap,mService service, ArrayList<List<String[]>> dMList ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHandler = listDataHandler;
        this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
        this.mService = service;
        this.deviceMList =dMList;
    }

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensors_list_items,null);
    }
    CheckedTextView txtListChild = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById((R.id.sensorsCheckedTextView));
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

if(mService.mPlotManager.ifPropertyExist(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition))) {
        txtListChild.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        txtListChild.setChecked(false);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your **mService** with a class named PlottingService, then try following changes to the adapter:

```
public class SignalsExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHandler;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> listHashMap;
    private PlottingService mService;

    public SignalsExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHandler, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap, PlottingService ps) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHandler = listDataHandler;
        this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
        this.mService = ps;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensors_list_items,null);
        }
        CheckedTextView txtListChild = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById((R.id.sensorsCheckedTextView));
        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        // Always set check state according to data.
        if(mService.mPlotManager.ifPropertyExist(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition))) {
            txtListChild.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            txtListChild.setChecked(false);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Inside Fragment, do Attempt 1, only change:
`listAdapter = new SignalsExpandableListAdapter(context,signalsListDataHeader,signalsListHash);`
to
`listAdapter = new SignalsExpandableListAdapter(context,signalsListDataHeader,signalsListHash, mService);`

Hope that helps!

**Updated:-** In Fragment, comment out the OnChildClickListener and in the adapter, use the following getChildView:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensors_list_items,null);
    }
    CheckedTextView txtListChild = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById((R.id.sensorsCheckedTextView));
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    // Always set check state according to data.
    if(mService.mPlotManager.ifPropertyExist(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition))) {
        txtListChild.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        txtListChild.setChecked(false);
    }

    txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckedTextView sensorCheckedView = (CheckedTextView)v;
            if(!sensorCheckedView.isChecked()) {
                sensorCheckedView.setChecked(true);
                try {
                    if(Plot==null) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Plot is null!");
                    }
                    mService.mPlotManager.addSignal(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition), Plot);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error!" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                mService.mPlotManager.removeSignal(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
                sensorCheckedView.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**Updated 2:-** In Fragment, comment out the OnChildClickListener and in the adapter, add a inner class and use the following getChildView:

```
class Position {
    int group, child;
    Position(int group, int child) {
        this.group = group;
        this.child = child;
    }
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sensors_list_items,null);
    }
    CheckedTextView txtListChild = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById((R.id.sensorsCheckedTextView));
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    // Always set check state according to data.
    if(mService.mPlotManager.ifPropertyExist(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition))) {
        txtListChild.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        txtListChild.setChecked(false);
    }

    txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckedTextView sensorCheckedView = (CheckedTextView)v;
            int groupPosition = ((Position)v.getTag()).group;
            int childPosition = ((Position)v.getTag()).child;
            if(!sensorCheckedView.isChecked()) {
                sensorCheckedView.setChecked(true);
                try {
                    if(Plot==null) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Plot is null!");
                    }
                    mService.mPlotManager.addSignal(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition), Plot);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error!" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                mService.mPlotManager.removeSignal(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
                sensorCheckedView.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
    txtListChild.setTag(new Position(groupPosition, childPosition));
    return view;
}
```

If **Updated 2** still have the issue of multiple checked items, then the possible cause is `mService.mPlotManager.ifPropertyExist(deviceMList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition))`. Instead of using **mService** to verify if an item is selected or not, it may be a better idea to change **listHashMap** from `HashMap<String, List<String>>` to `HashMap<String, List<ChildItem>>` [The accepted answer in [Values of counter changes after scrolling ExpendableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092400/values-of-counter-changes-after-scrolling-expendablelistview), you need a boolean field instead of the integer field, quantity]. Then when a child item is clicked, check and update with the list.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this. I was not able to access`deviceMList` inside adapter so I added `private ArrayList<List<String[]>> deviceMList` also to Adapter and it was modified similarly. Now I can check/uncheck. But it still seems like something is going wrong. I cannot see the `checked` mark real-time. When I click a child then I want to scroll up/down to visually see the checkmark. Same as with the uncheck. It is strange. Any idea about that please? I will update my question with this attempt and strange behavior observed.

Comment: I don't find anything about such a strange result. Try the **Updated** and see if it fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it (in addition to that adapter was updated with plot & Log_TAG as input arguments), but it is strange. Now I can see the checkmark right after I click the child but when I scroll my list to bottom another item is also checked ( checkmark is running).  When I check once what I observed is always on the screen there is a check-in one item no matter what it is. Kind of check state is changing to current visualizing items. If I check 2 items and scroll down, I can see another 2 items are checked always in the screen somehow 2 items are checked.

Comment: I'm not sure why the 'check' mark is moving not to fix.  I have a whole main activity > inside that this service activity > inside that expandable list is in one fragment.

Comment: I've made an **Updated 2** and added some suggestions. If that fixed your problem, then I've another suggestion for you: If **childText** are short that using list format is a bit waste of space, then take a look of my answers in these 2 links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914836/checkbox-for-gridview-inside-listview-in-android, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288713/expandablelistview-with-viewpager-combination-as-its-child Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow! amazing now it is working! Thank you very much for your help. I followed your **Updated 2** and it works!